# Copy or scp files to /var/lib/boot2docker for boot2docker VM managed by docker-machine

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

To use Docker on OS X, I'm using a boot2docker VM running in VirtualBox, managed by docker-machine. The [boot2docker documents mention a persistence volume `/var/lib/boot2docker`](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md#local-customisation-with-persistent-partition). I would like to copy a file `bootlocal.sh` on the host filesystem over to the boot2docker VM.

I thought that [docker-machine's `scp` command](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/scp/) would work for this,

```
docker-machine scp bootlocal.sh dockerhost:/var/lib/boot2docker/
```

Unfortunately, this gives

```
scp: /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh: Permission denied
exit status 1
```

Checking the file permissions, we can see that `root` is the only one with write permissions to this directory, by default:

```
docker@dockerhost:~$ ll -d /var/lib/boot2docker
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            29 May 31 17:40 /var/lib/boot2docker -> /mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/
docker@dockerhost:~$ ll -d /mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker
drwxr-xr-x    6 root     root          4096 May 31 17:40 /mnt/sda1/var/lib/boot2docker/
```

It is not possible to specify the user `root` as the one to use with `docker-machine scp`.

How does one copy files to `/var/lib/boot2docker`, preferably from the host machine?

Answer (score 1):

I could not find a way to do this using `docker-machine scp`. I did discover that, at least for OS X, the `/Users` directory of the host machine is mounted as a volume in the docker-machine VM, meaning that if the file is within the host file system under that directory, the VM can access it verbatim.

Knowing this, my workaround was to use `docker-machine ssh` to issue a `cp` command for the files I needed transferred.

```
docker-machine ssh dockerhost sudo cp /Users/username/path/to/bootlocal.sh /var/lib/boot2docker/
```